# how to run gluu by docker? I need a docker-compose sample

Tags: docker-compose, gluu

can any one help me to run gluu by docker. i can't find any docker-compose.
I found this:

https://github.com/GluuFederation/gluu-docker

but it didn't work (That wasn't straight forward and has some complexity without any useful help and documentation). I just need starter kit to run gluu locally with docker-compose